# trouble Rolling up total sales to a single line in T-sql

Tags: t-sql

I pull a list of purchases from our customers for a 12 month period.  Info includes lots of info about their purchase including their Finance ID, account # and specifics about their purchase.  I want to roll it up to a single line for each item number purchased for the full year no matter how many they purchased on which date.  I want to see the total "ea" and total sales.  Sounds simple I know.

I tried to sum those two categories and use a group by clause but I still get several lines for each facility because the dates are different or the qty is different etc.  If I knock out a lot of the detail I want, i can get to the single line but I need more info.

select
 FID
,account_number
,Account_Name
,facility,
,Sum(total_purcahse_ea) as total_ea
,Sum(Total_Sales) as total_sales
,mfr_nbr
,Item_Class_nbr

Group by
 FID
,account_number
,Account_Name
,facility,
,mfr_nbr
,Item_Class_nbr

since there can be several account numbers per FID, and their can be several account names under each account number, I am getting several lines of the same mfr_nbr for the same facility because the invoice dates are different or because the total ea purchased is different.  Not sure.  I just want to get something like this:
FID Account_nbr  Account_name  facility Total_ea Total_sales mfr# item_class #
123   0051           Tom's         west    16        1600     a605   da559

and not 10 lines that total 16 ea at $1600

Comment: You cannot have one row of aggregated data and multiple lines of detail. You say there "can be several account names under each account number". If you want just one line how do you want to choose which account name to display? Also, if you applied some formatting to your question it would make it easier to read.

Comment: Can you add some sample data of your input and your output, it will help a lot.